# What non IE software version to use to check compatability with IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer-6

Hope this question is not stupid since I am an amateur web designer. I use Windows 7 and want to see the website I make works decently with something like IE6 (will be using html and css only).

But instead of going through all the mess of download virtual machine software and such from MS, I was wondering if there is any other browser like old Firefox or Netscape that I can install from filehippo if they give the results similar to Internet Explorer 6?

Comment: This looks pretty good http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: [Using the actual browser version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) is really the only way (if you want 100% certainty in your testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how precise you need to be with your tests.

The easiest option has already been mentioned in the comments -- [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It's a wrapper for IE that supports running all versions of IE, from 5.5 up to v9, all in the same window. It's extremely useful for testing how a site will look in older versions of IE; I use it all the time.

Unfortunately, it is not very stable; it crashes a lot, especially when you're running IE6 or IE7 in it. It also doesn't cope well with plugin elements such as flash. If your site uses them a lot, you may be out of luck.

But if you can cope with the limitations, then this is a good program, and it does directly answer your question.

More specifically, you were hoping an older non-IE browser could be used to simulate IE6. Sadly not. IE is unique (in a bad way); it has features, bugs and quirks that don't appear in any other browser either now or in the past.

The closest you'll get might be a really old version of Opera -- in their early days, they made a point of trying to get good compatibility with IE, to the point of implementing a number of IE's proprietary features. But even then, it was never that close.

One really cheeky alternative might be to use [Wine](http://www.winehq.com/) to install IE6 onto a Linux box. Again, it's likely to be unstable, but it has been known to work. I haven't tried it for a while, but it worked okay back then, and Wine has improved a lot in the meanwhile.

Beyond that, the only real option is to run a genuine copy of IE6. The best way to do that is to install a VM with a full copy of XP on it. Not great, but in truth this is the only way you'll get a really 100% accurate picture of what your IE6 users are seeing. If that matters to you then you need to do this.

But to be honest, in most cases it won't matter about it being 100%. IETester is sufficiently good for testing most sites, and frankly if you have the odd glitch left over, don't worry about it too much -- IE6 users are well used to the web not working very well for them these days.

Make it work; don't make it perfect. And for that, IETester should be plenty good enough.

Comment: You convince me to use IETester! Thank you.

Comment: @LWTBP - if you're using the answer, click the tick icon next to the answer to show that you've accepted it. (Also, click the up arrow to give it a score, but you can't do that until you've earned some points yourself, so for now just the tick is fine).

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is notorious for misbehaving. There is no other program that isn't IE6 that acts like IE6.

My suggestion would be to use a site like [Adobe's BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html). It lets you pick a URL and then it takes snapshots of what it looks like on different browser's as well as operating systems. The list is far from complete but it's one of the best free solutions that I've found.

Comment: I want to +1 your answer for the first sentence alone... 100% correct.  Only IE6 reliably behaves like IE6.  But then your second paragraph lost me.  Not only will that method introduce its own issues and/or rendering bugs... it's only a snapshot.  Most sites today contain dynamic content that a snapshot cannot possibly test.

Comment: I agree that BrowserLab is far from ideal, especially considering the limitations of just looking at a picture. But I thought that it was worth mentioning because it's free and LWTBP said it was just a HTML/CSS website.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. BrowserLab is quite a good idea especially if I want to see how it LOOKS instead of how it behaves. Thanks again.